# Ruby Net/SSH - reload bash_profile

Tags: ruby, bash, net-ssh

I'm using Ruby MRI 1.8.7 and I have a Net-SSH script that connects to a server and edits the .bash_profile file.
Basically a few alias shortcuts are added.
Example of .bash_profile content:

```
alias test="echo 'test'"
```

Now, I cannot use those aliases until I reload via source .bash_profile..
The problem is that it seems like I cannot source .bash_profile via Net-SSH.
This is what I've tried so far:

```
ssh.exec!("source .bash_profile")
ssh.exec!("source /root/.bash_profile")
ssh.exec!("bash -c 'source ~/.bash_profile'")
```

Now, actually I don't even need the aliases in Net-SSH, but I at least don't want to source bash_profile manually on the server.
What is the issue here, and are there any solutions to that?

Comment: Have you tried to execute a command inline with the `source` to see what happens? (e.g. `source ~/.bash_profile && test`)

Comment: yes it works fine. are you implying that there shouldn't be anything different with the Ruby/SSH session?

Comment: I meant have you tried executing that command via Ruby/SSH. Perhaps the sourcing isn't persisting between `ssh.exec!` statements.

Comment: ah, I understand. It didn't work though: "bash: test1: command not found\n" (from .bash_profile: alias test1="echo 'test'")

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am having this exact issue.

Comment: I never found a solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a bang (!) in a double-quoted string in bash.  Try this:
`alias test='echo ''test!'''`

Comment: thanks I edited my post. However this is just an illustrative example, so the actual content was irrelevant. In my real life example the alias/shortcut works fine when sourcing bash_profile manually (source ~/.bash_profile && test), but not when sourcing it via Ruby/SSH

Answer (score 0):

puts

```
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

at **first line** of .bashrc